# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'load.php'

Tags: errors, fatal-error

I'm getting the following errors on my WordPress site

```
Warning: require(/home/[site]/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[site]/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19

Warning: require(/home/[site]/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[site]/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/[site]/public_html/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/[site]/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19
```

I've been troubleshooting for a few days but could really use some help.

**File permissions:**

wp-settings.php: 644

wp-config.php: 444

wp-includes: 755

wp-includes/load.php: 644

Anyone know what it could be? I've tried manually upgrading the files(deleting the old wp-files and updating), but still nothing. PHP version is 7.

Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of PHP and other server settings that might be causing this.  There's a great (highly voted, 500 point bounty) answer over on StackOverflow at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/6347850 that might help you if this is still unresolved.

Answer (score -1):

I think there  is a permission issue with these files
Reset the permissions or overwrite it from a fresh install. But be sure that it's the same version.

All files should be 664.
All folders should be 775.
wp-config.php should be 660.

Comment: I changed the files to be this configuration to no avail. I am still seeing this error.

Comment: Messages say that file is not found, it has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: Permission, php version or database problem...

Look here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/261686/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: One more thing to try - if you have a child theme, check your functions.php. If there is a closing tag ?> delete this. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302113/wsod-for-admin-when-using-php-7/

Answer (score -1):

Try uploading "load.php" in binary transfer mode.

Deactivate or delete plugins and try.

Comment: This had no effect either. Plugins were deleted as well.